# Unauthorised request in Mailjet

Tags: scala, mailjet

i'm using MailJet Java Api to send email, i write this code en scala:

```
object Main {
  var client: MailjetClient = null
  var request: MailjetRequest = _
  var response: MailjetResponse = _

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    client = new MailjetClient(System.getenv("MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC"), System.getenv("MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE"))
    request = new MailjetRequest(Email.resource)
      .property(Email.FROMEMAIL, "pilot@mailjet.com")
      .property(Email.FROMNAME, "Pilot")
      .property(Email.SUBJECT, "Your mail !!!!")
      .property(Email.TO, "passenger@mailjet.com")
    response = client.post(request)
    println(response.getStatus)
    println(response.getData)

  }
```

but i get `401 Unauthorized`, although my public API key and private are corrects.do you have any idea

Comment: Hi, 

I lead the API at Mailjet.

Could you please submit a ticket so we can discuss what's going here in better details? https://app.mailjet.com/support/ticket

Thanks for having chosen Mailjet to power your email.

Comment: Done, thank you sir

Comment: Welcome, hope we can get this sorted out quickly

Comment: Please provide the solution here on stack overflow.

Comment: would love to see the solution here as well...  copy pasting from the website and getting 401.